# Equality proof $- (-1)^n = 0$ using induction

Tags: calculus

I have two equalities that I need to prove. Well, let's start with the first and then I'll try the second. First is -

$$ \sum^n_{i=0}(-1)^{i} \binom{n}{i} =0 $$

Of course, when you try one, it works:

$$ n=1 \rightarrow (-1)^{0} \binom{1}{0}+(-1)^{1} \binom{1}{1}=0 $$

But I'm stuck when trying to prove it in induction for $n=+1 $ and the main reason, I think, is because I'm not sure how to use the binom.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Pascal, Pascal, Pascal. That's one hint in the induction step.

Comment: $\binom nk = \binom{n-1}{k-1} + \binom{n-1}k$. Use this if necessary. (though the formula is famous).  (I mean $(a+b)^{n}= \sum_{i=0}^{n} \binom ni a^{i}b^{n-i}$). (Just take $a=1$ and $b=-1$).

Comment: This is the **binomial theorem** on $(1-1)^n$.

Comment: Thanks to everyone! I guess I simply used the binomial theorem, though I didn't prove it in the process.

Now, the second equation I'm having trouble with, is this:

$$ \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{2n}{2k} = 2^{2n-1} $$

I tried using the identity given above, but still. I did try using the binom this way:

$$ (1+1)^{2n-1} $$

But then I'm not sure how to continue with the $2n-1$.